# escuchar cambios en el estado de una cuenta en firebase Authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase

estoy creando una app android usando firebase autenticacion pero no logro detectar cuando un usuario aya sido inhabilitado o eliminado desde la consola este cogigo que implemento desde firebase no lo hace me permite continuar como estando logueado aunque inhabilite la cuenta, no he podido encontrar un evento que se genere y sea detectado en la app, o un método que me permita consultar el estado de una cuenta en tiempo real

```
 java
       @Override
           public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
             // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
              FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
             if (currentUser!=null){updateUI(currentUser);}
              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El evento que tenes programado, solo chequea cuando se inicia la app, ya que esta en el metodo onStart() , por lo que no va a seguir teniendo efecto durante el uso de la app.

Cuando inicias sesion con Firebase, se genera un token de sesion que tiene un tiempo de caducidad , por lo que borrando desde la base de datos no va a hacer que tu usuario se borre, ya que desde la solapa authentication aun esta el registro del mail de ese usuario y su password almacenada en un hash.

Para solucionar tu problema podes hacer lo siguiente

Podes atachar una referencia al nodo del usuario en la base de datos y preguntar si existe ese nodo, si existe quiere decir que el usuario aun persiste en la base de datos, si no existe quiere decir que el usuario no existe mas en la base de datos, por lo tanto si no existe y esta conectado, podes hacerle un logout.

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

mDatabase.child("Usuarios").child(userID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){
      FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
      startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
     }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("Fallo la lectura: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

Donde userID es

```
String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Al usar `addValueEventListener` estamos atachando un listener a la referencia que siempre va a estar escuchando por cambios, cuando apenas borremos el usuario de la base de datos, se va a disparar el trigger y como no existe ese usuario lo va a redirigir a la ventana de login, recorda tambien eliminar el usuario de authentication desde Firebase para que no quede guardada la cuenta, de otro modo va a poder iniciar sesion, pero si no te importa que la cuenta quede, podes borrar los datos desde la base y ya ese usuario no tendria nada al volver a ingresar

Comment: eres un pro gracias

Comment: Si te sirvió podría marcar la respuesta como correcta ? Gracias